# How to import data containing double quotes into mongodb using mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I'm using mongoimport to import a csv file.  The csv file contains text with imbedded double quotes on the 2nd line.

```
"id","text"
"1","This is text"
"2","\"This is quoted text\""
```

This should import as two lines with the 2nd line including the beginning and ending quotes as part of the text.  However mongoimport responds with:

```
c:\mongoimport -d testdb -c testtb --headerline --type csv --drop --file c:/temp1.csv
connected to: localhost
dropping: testdb.testtb
Failed: read error on entry #2: line 3, column 6: extraneous " in field
   imported 0 documents    error "read error: bare " in non-quoted field imported 0 documents.
```

How do you import csv data containing double quotes within quoted fields?  Is there another escape method?

My environment is Windows based.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a reference in the Mongoimport docs to this, here
https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption--type

> The csv parser accepts that data that complies with RFC RFC 4180. As a
>   result, backslashes are not a valid escape character. If you use
>   double-quotes to enclose fields in the CSV data, you must escape
>   internal double-quote marks by prepending another double-quote.

So to make things clear: instead of escaping double-quotes with a backslash, you need to escape a double-quote with another double-quote, i.e. as a result you need to have two double-quotes.